# Power Query or Power BI - If cell is blank then copy value from the closest row above the said cell

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot

how can one achieve this either in Power Query or Power BI. If cell is blank then copy the closest row above it. Data from SAP is just weird looking.

FILL DOWN does not work on text I guess but it worked with my first column (IDs),

See image below.

[image]

Comment: Fill Up/Down Works irrespective of the data type. You can you use.

Comment: Well, it did not work for my case. I am using Power Query.

Comment: I think I solved it, I need to replace blanks with nulls before doing the fill downs.

Comment: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-forum/power-query/fill-down-not-working